# Get all sequences in binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I have a binary tree and I need to get all sequences between the leaves and the root.
For example, for such tree
[image: tree]

I need to get the sequences: "ABD", "ABE", "AC".
How to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: You should be more precise about what you really want to achieve

Comment: @pjam: user wants all possible paths from the root node to the leaves

Comment: I have a binary tree(not BST or binary heap). Each node contains some value(A, B, C... in example above). As a result, I need to get something like: String[leaves_count] seq = ["ABD", "ABE", "AC"]. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code :

```
Function ProcessNode(TreeNode, ParentPath)
  CurrentPath = Append(ParentPath, TreeNode.Name)
  If IsNull(TreeNode.Left) And IsNull(TreeNode.Right) Then
    Print(CurrentPath)
  Else
    If IsNotNull(TreeNode.Left) Then ProcessNode(TreeNode.Left, CurrentPath)
    If IsNotNull(TreeNode.Right) Then ProcessNode(TreeNode.Right, CurrentPath)


ProcessNode(Root, "")
```